# Set the Authentication Token Profile Header

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have an OpenIdConnect Server I'm connecting to an I would like to forward token data the first time logging in to be stored on the server.  Currently I'm doing this to forward the access token

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onload = function () {
    log(xhr.status, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
}
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + user.access_token);
xhr.send();
```

I want to send the Profile Data as well but I don't know the proper header.
How can I do something like this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization-Profile", "Bearer " + user.profile);
```

Does anyone know the proper header so I can add these claims to the access token.

Comment: Does the server accept user profile in the request header? Profile data is generally passed in the request body.

Comment: @TejSoft can you provide an example

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what we did in one of our project:

Created a common API response class as below:

```
public class ApiCommonResponse
{
    public object Object { get; set; }
    public int httpStatus { get; set; }
    public string httpErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And a generic method to call GET and POST API endpoints. This method will map the response to the supplied data model and will return you the object.

```
public static ApiCommonResponse GetApiData<T>(string token, T dataModel, string apiEndPoint = null)
{
    var responseText = "";
    var apiCommonResponse = new ApiCommonResponse();
    if (apiEndPoint != null)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiEndPoint);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.Headers.Add("X-Api-Version", "");
        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream != null)
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            var stream = we.Response.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream != null)
            {
                var resp = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);
                throw new Exception(obj.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore };
    apiCommonResponse.Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText, jsonSettings);
    apiCommonResponse.httpStatus = 0;
    return apiCommonResponse;
}

public static ApiCommonResponse PostApiData<T>(string username, string token, T dataModel, string apiEndPoint = null)
{
    var apiCommonResponse = new ApiCommonResponse();

    if (apiEndPoint == null) return null;

    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(apiEndPoint);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("X-Api-Version", "");

    using (var requeststreams = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(requeststreams))
        {
            sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataModel));
        }
    }
    try
    {
        var httpStatus = (((HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()).StatusCode);
        var httpMessage = (((HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()).StatusDescription);
        using (var s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (s == null) return null;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                var responseObj = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseObj))
                {
                    apiCommonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiCommonResponse>(responseObj);
                }
            }
            apiCommonResponse.httpStatus = (int)httpStatus;
            apiCommonResponse.httpErrorMessage = httpMessage;
            apiCommonResponse.Object = apiCommonResponse.Object;

        }
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        var stream = we.Response.GetResponseStream();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            var resp = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);
            throw new Exception(obj.ToString());
        }
    }
    return apiCommonResponse;
}
```

Comment: The example I gave shows how to GET and POST data along with a bearer token in the header. Now, question is how is the server expecting the user profile? One option is to call POST api and supply user profile in the body.

Comment: I'm trying get this to be read with the other claims so I have access to the name etc

Comment: If I have to create this separately I can create a webapi endpoint

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement in here. Identity server itself is the source of user profile. I used to get user profile from identity server itself, not the other way around. If user data needed to be sent to the ID server then better to send it as a post data.

Comment: I guess but then I'd have to parse it on the client instead of just pass it along

Comment: Just deserialise and bind it to a data model at the client side.

Comment: If that's the only way then okay